# How to solve VueJS calculator working once?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, calculator

I have finished my calculator using VueJS, HTML and CSS but it works once. I mean, if I set 6x3 it gives me 18 but if I erase the result and I set other numbers, 3 x 2 for example, it does not work and is placed as 32. This is not solve until I reload the webpage and it is a loop that I cannot solve for not. I need help please.

Here it is the code in HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calcolatrice</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Calcss.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link rel="icon" href="Cal.png">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Belanosima:wght@600&family=Pangolin&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="Tittolo">
        <div class="barra"> 
            <h1>DraCanculator</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tutto">
        <div id="app">
            <div id="calcolatri">
                <div id="schermo">{{numCorrente}}</div>
                    <div @click="segno" class="btn">-/+</div>
                    <div @click="percento" class="btn">%</div>
                    <div @click="log" class="btn">log</div>
                    <div @click="cancella" class="btn operatore">C</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(7)" class="btn">7</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(8)" class="btn">8</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(9)" class="btn">9</div>
                    <div @click="divisione" class="btn operatore">÷</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(4)" class="btn">4</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(5)" class="btn">5</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(6)" class="btn">6</div>
                    <div @click="moltiplica" class="btn operatore">x</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(1)" class="btn">1</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(2)" class="btn">2</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(3)" class="btn">3</div>
                    <div @click="resta" class="btn operatore">-</div>
                    <div @click="inserici(0)" class="btn">0</div>
                    <div @click="puntoop" class="btn">.</div>
                    <div @click="uguale" class="btn operatore">=</div>
                    <div @click="suma" class="btn operatore">+</div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div id="ciao">
                <img :src="ci" alt="Cipheros Img." style="width: 50px; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);"/>
                <p style="font-size: 10px;">
                Made by Cipheros.
                </p>
            </div>
    </div> 
<script src="CalJs.js"></script>  
<script>
    new Vue ({
        el: "#ciao",
        data: {
            ci: 'Cipheros.png'
        },  
    });
</script>  
</body>
</html>

Here is the CSS code: 
'''
body {
    background-color: #2c2929;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Belanosima', sans-serif;
    font-family: 'Pangolin', cursive; 
}
.barra {
    background-color: rgb(57, 165, 105);;
    padding: 1px 0;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
    margin-bottom: 3%;
}
h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.tutto {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 40px;
    gap: 15px;
}
#calcolatri {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(40px, auto);
    width: 80vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    background-color: #595757;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#schermo{
    display: grid;
    grid-column: 1/5;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
}
.btn {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 1.5px;
    background-color: #807d7d;
}
.operatore{
background-color: mediumseagreen;
}
#ciao{
    gap: 1px;
}
'''

And here is the JS code, using VueJS.
'''
new Vue ({
    el: '#calcolatri',
    data:{
        numCorrente: '',
        operazione: '',
        cliccato: false
    },
    methods:{
        inserici(numero){
            if (this.cliccato){
            this.numCorrente = '';
            this.cliccato = false
            } 
            this.numCorrente = `${this.numCorrente}${numero}`;
        },
        cancella(){
            this.numCorrente = '';
        },
        segno() {
            this.numCorrente = this.numCorrente.charAt(0) === '-' ?
                this.numCorrente.slice(1) : `-${this.numCorrente}`;
        },
        puntoop(){
            if (this.numCorrente.indexOf('.') === -1){
                this.inserici('.');
            }
        },
        percento(){
            this.numCorrente = `${parseFloat(this.numCorrente) / 100 }`
        },

        log(){
            this.operazione = `log(${this.numCorrente})`;
            this.numCorrente = `${Math.log(parseFloat(this.numCorrente))}`;
        },

        precedente(){
            this.precedente = this.numCorrente
            this.cliccato = true;
        },

        moltiplica(){
            this.operatore = (a, b) => a * b;
            this.precedente();
        },

        suma(){
            this.operatore = (a, b) => a + b;
            this.precedente();
        },

        resta(){
            this.operatore = (a, b) => a - b;
            this.precedente();
        },

        divisione(){
            this.operatore = (a, b) => a / b;
            this.precedente();
        },
        uguale(){

            if (this.operazione) {
                this.numCorrente = `${this.operazione} = ${this.numCorrente}`;
                this.operazione = '';
            }
            else
            this.numCorrente = `${this.operatore(
                parseFloat(this.precedente),
                parseFloat(this.numCorrente),
            )}`
            this.precedente = null;

        },
    }
});
'''


I would like to solve that please, the calculator working forever instead once.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAq2F.png)
```

Answer (score 0):

**The problem:**

`precedente()` is a method, but you are changing it to a variable and setting it as `null` in two places, which is breaking the code that then tries to call it as a method.

1. Inside the `precedente()` method with `this.precedente = this.numCorrente;`
2. Inside `uguale()` method with `this.precedente = null;`

**To fix:**

Change the name of the variable wherever you use `this.precedente` (without the two `()` brackets) to a different name.

For example, change it to `precedenteNum`:

```
precedente() {
    this.precedenteNum = this.numCorrente; // changed | cambiato
    this.cliccato = true;
},

uguale() {
    if (this.operazione) {
        this.numCorrente = `${this.operazione} = ${this.numCorrente}`;
        this.operazione = '';
    } else {
        this.numCorrente = `${this.operatore(
            parseFloat(this.precedenteNum), // changed | cambiato
            parseFloat(this.numCorrente)
        )}`;
    }
    this.precedenteNum = null; // changed | cambiato
},
```